# DataGridTemplateColumn Styling for Disabled Controls WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a `DataGrid` control in my WPF application, and I have a checkbox column as one of the columns.  I am using a `DataGridTemplate` to build the data grid.  My goal is to change the background color of any checkbox data grid cell where the checkbox is disabled.  My checkbox column looks like this:

```
<!-- style for the checkbox column cells -->
<Style x:Key="DefaultCheckboxCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyCheckBoxColumn" CellStyle="{StaticResource DefaultCheckboxCellStyle}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="chk" IsChecked="{Binding MyChkChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=MyChkEnabled}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

Nothing I am doing seems to change the cell background for disabled checkboxes.  I am displaying disabled checkboxes, but all of the cells themselves are still enabled.  Is there a way to bind the enabled value from the inner checkbox control to the cell?  If so, I could use that in my trigger.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the checkboxes, as you've, found, won't disable the cells. There are a couple of ways to go about this.

One is to have the Style trigger bind to the same viewmodel property that disables the checkbox. This belongs in `DefaultCheckboxCellStyle`, replacing the one trigger you have.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTriger Binding="{Binding MyChkEnabled}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
    </DataTriger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Or you could try this in `DefaultCheckboxCellStyle`: Keep the trigger you have, and disable the actual cell. You could then omit the other XAML that disables the checkbox itself, as it's a child of the cell anyway.

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MyChkEnabled}" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is a no-op there, by the way.